# Where is this function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can see this in a query within an application (I'm *assuming* where I have 'functionName' that it's actually a function:

```
functionName @oldServer='[*servername*]',@newServer='[*servername*]'
```

When I look for custom functions in the database that this is running against (by doing this):

```
USE *databaseName*
GO

SELECT 
    name AS function_name
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,type_desc
FROM 
    sys.objects
WHERE 
    type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';
GO
```

I don't find any function called 'functionName'.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: Have you checked the master database?

Comment: Thanks, just seems to have system functions there...

Comment: Have you checked synonyms?

Comment: If there are no parentheses around the parameters, it's not a function. It's probably a stored procedure. And is there a reason you can't share the "functionName" with us?

Comment: please got to the object explorer and script the function out and show us it's header.

Comment: trace it with profiler.

Comment: Thanks Preet, ErikeE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE
   ROUTINE_NAME LIKE '%function%'
```

**An important thing to remember is whether you have a CASE SENSITIVE collation or a CASE INSENSITIVE collation**. If you have the first then you need to ensure that query is using the correct case for the function name etc.

---

Here is an example I just created on my machine:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction]
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction]
(
    @Parameter1 INT, 
    @Parameter2 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ret INT

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @ret = @Parameter1 + @Parameter2

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ret

END

GO

select dbo.TestFunction(1, 2);

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE
    ROUTINE_NAME like '%function%'
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't show me anything though, either when checking against the master DB or the one that the function(?) is being run against.  What is this doing?

Comment: @Chris Where it says `LIKE '%function%"` you should put in your function name, like `LIKE '%functionName%'`.